# Temporarily undo changes made in past commit

Tags: git

I have some hard bug to find. I used git bisect to find the commit, and I reach that commit.

I want to make sure this is the code that introduced the bug (I'm not that certain)
so I want to temporarily undo the changes made by that commit (42b58), test the code, and then redo the changes (its a past commit, so no reason to keep that)

consider that I am at that commit (the final stage of git bisect),

How do I undo the changes of commit 42b58 (current commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just *checkout* the commit before it:

```
git checkout 42b58^
```

Answer (score 1):

use checkout command `git checkout 42b58~1`